# Qual a diferença entre chaves e parênteses em uma arrow function no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funções, característica-linguagem, sintaxe, arrow-functions

Qual é a diferença relevante entre chaves (`{ }`) e parênteses (`( )`) em um retorno de uma função?

```
const example = () => ( ... );
```

Versus:

```
const example = () => { ... };
```

Comment: Colchete vai retornar a última instrução. Chave não vai retornar nada. A não ser que você defina com `return`, como em uma função/método qualquer...

Comment: Se quiser escreve uma resposta, exemplifique, etc ... @LipESprY

Comment: Faço isso amanhã se ninguém formular uma resposta. Por isso comentei "o relevante". Tô de passagem.

Comment: Acho que vale a pena trocar o título da pergunta para "Qual a diferença entre {} e () em uma arrow function no JavaScript", uma vez que este não é um recurso _exclusivo_ do React, mas do JavaScript. O que acha? :)

Comment: @LuizFelipe fiz a alteração.

Comment: Colchetes ou parenteses?

Comment: `() => ( )`, assim vazio, é erro de sintaxe... ou a dúvida é com algo dentro de `()`?

Comment: @sam editado e obrigado.

Comment: @Sergio não é vazio ... é com instrução, como vai se comportar, obrigado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Antes de tudo, vale ressaltar que isso não se trata de algo exclusivo do React. É um recurso sintático do JavaScript. Foi introduzido no ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), com a adição das *arrow functions*. Entre os vários recursos introduzidos por essa nova forma de se criar uma função, pode-se citar a avaliação de um bloco de código ou uma única expressão.

---

Os métodos mais antigos para se definir funções funções no JavaScript exigem que você necessariamente crie um bloco. Por exemplo:

```js
function doStuff() {
  // Eu sou um bloco!
}

const doOtherStuff = function() {
  // Eu sou um bloco!
};
```

As *arrow functions*, por outro lado, não. Permitem ao desenvolvedor optar por utilizar uma única expressão. Se necessário, claro, blocos ainda podem ser usados para ser o corpo (*body*) da *arrow function*.

Desse modo, se a sua *arrow function* retorna algo entre parênteses `()`, significa que seu corpo é uma única expressão, que será avaliada durante sua invocação. Vale frisar que não é necessário usar parênteses para denotar uma expressão. Nesse caso específico, geralmente os parênteses são colocados em expressões que ocuparão múltiplas linhas, como vários componentes JSX, que são expressões, já que, no fundo, não passam de chamadas à [`React.createElement`](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement).

```js
const fn1 = () => 'Hello, world!';

const fn2 = (x, y) => x + y;

const fn3 = (x, y, z) => (
  x +
  y +
  z
);

console.log(fn1());
console.log(fn2(1, 2));
console.log(fn3(1, 2, 3));
```

Já se a *arrow function* tiver sido definida com as chaves (`{}`), seu corpo será um bloco, que poderá executar múltiplas expressões e declarações (statements). Nesse caso, a função retornará um valor definido explicitamente através do `return`. Caso contrário, `undefined` será retornado.

Alguns exemplos da *arrow function* cujo corpo (*body*) seja um bloco:

```js
const fn1 = () => {
  return 'Olá, mundo!'
};

const fn2 = (x, y) => {
  // `if` é um exemplo de declaração (statement):
  if (x > y) {
    return 'X é maior que Y.';
  }
};

console.log(fn1()); // Olá, mundo!
console.log(fn2(9, 1)); // X é maior que Y.
console.log(fn2(1, 9)); // undefined
```

Embora isso não tenha sido colocado na pergunta, vale lembrar que os parênteses também podem ser utilizados para agrupar várias expressões (separadas por vírgulas), avaliando uma a uma mas retornando somente a última. Veja mais na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping).

Para aprofundamento, sugiro a leitura [deste capítulo](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_syntax.html#statement-vs-expression) do excelente livro "JavaScript for impatient programmers", que cobre as diferenças entre expressões e declarações.

Comment: Você terminou a resposta na metade da minha, mas coloquei mesmo assim por causa do último item que não mencionou, já tive problemas com isso e demorei pra entender o erro

Answer (score 8):

Isso não tem nada a ver com React, JSX ou qualquer biblioteca ou superset (TypeScript, por exemplo), são apenas sintaxes do JavaScript:

Na **segunda**, as chaves definem o início e fim de um bloco de código, que pode ter múltplias expressões e outros blocos de código, separados por `;` ou quebra de linha:

```
() => {
   foo();bar()
   for (const fun of functions) {
       fun()
   }
}
```

Ao definir as chaves, a função não retornará nada (ou seja, `undefined`) a não ser que seja feito explicitamente com a palavra chave `return`

A **primeira** é apenas um parênteses para agrupar uma expressão, que será retornada pela função, logo `() => (qualquercoisa)` é equivalente a `() => qualquercoisa`, geralmente é usado para deixar claro o início e fim da expressão:

```
() => (
    <div className="alert">
        <p>Um exemplo qualquer</p>
    </div>
)
```

Se você quiser retornar um objeto literal, seu uso é necessário para que as chaves não sejam confundidas com o início e fim do bloco de código, o que geraria um erro de sintaxe:

```
// Correto
() => ({
    foo: 'bar'
})

// Erro
() => {
    foo: 'bar'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ambas respostas anteriores já definem bem a diferença. Só faltou ressaltar uma questão:

Ao usar os parênteses, automaticamente **será retornado a última expressão**.

Exemplo:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 10;
var c;
var d;

var foo = () => (c = a+b, a);
console.log(foo()); // define o valor de 'c' retorna 'a' (10)
console.log(c) // 20

var bar = () => (d = a+b, c = d+a, d);
console.log(bar()); // define o valor de 'd', 'c' e retorna 'd' (20)
console.log(c); // 30
```

Quando se quer retornar apenas uma expressão, não faz sentido usar os parênteses. Vira uma questão de estética.

Exemplo:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 10;

var fuba = () => a+b;

console.log(fuba()); // 20
```

Vale ressaltar, também, que caso tenha mais de uma expressão **sem delimitar com os parênteses**, a primeira será retornada **apesar de executar as demais**.

Exemplo:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 10;
var c;

var foo = () => c = a+b, a = 50;

console.log(foo()); // define o valor de 'c' (a+b), 'a' (50) e retorna 'c' (60)
console.log(c) // 60
```

Comment: Acho que vale constar que não são os parênteses que criam esse comportamento de retornar a última expressão. Isso é uma capacidade do operador `,` (_comma operator_). [Saiba mais aqui.](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch09.html#comma_operator)

Comment: @LuizFelipe muito bem colocado! Mas se vc usa os parênteses, é bom saber que será retornado a ultima expressão. Certo? Qualquer pequeno detalhe ajuda o leitor.

Comment: Sim, é algo que ajuda a entender, embora o comportamento seja causado pela vírgula, e não pelos parênteses. :)