# Object Destructuring e Map - Dúvida com Arrow Function

Tags: javascript

Estava vendo uma aula sobre esse assunto e fui reproduzir o código, mas com *arrow function*.

Estava assim:

```js
const heroes = [
  { name: 'Batman', realName: 'Bruce Wayne' },

  { name: 'Joker', realName: 'Arthur Fleck'}
];

const names = heroes.map(
  function({ name }) {
    return name;
  }
);

console.log (names) // ["Batman","Joker"]
```

E resolvi tentar colocar com *arrow function*, pensando que iria ter o mesmo resultado, naquela parte coloquei desse jeito:

```js
const heroes = [
  { name: 'Batman', realName: 'Bruce Wayne' },

  { name: 'Joker', realName: 'Arthur Fleck'}
];

const names = heroes.map( (name) => {
   return name;
 });
 
console.log(names)
```

Mas o resultado deu diferente, printou `name` e `realName`, o objeto inteiro dos dois.

Comment: Então Rayane, sua dúvida é a mesma que tive há um bom tempo, então provavelmente vai ser marcado como pergunta repetida. Você pode encontrar o post em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/472205/diferen%c3%a7as-entre-definir-m%c3%a9todos-de-objetos-utilizando-arrow-function-e-function

Comment: @t_carvalho e @Augusto, não creio ser duplicada porque as funções não estão sendo usadas como métodos e nem sequer fazem uso do `this`. Na verdade o problema foi usar *destructuring assignment* na `function` e não usar na *arrow function* (conforme resposta abaixo)

Comment: Eu queria mesmo é ter _votado_ para reabrir, mas o meu voto é martelado em JavaScript, então acabou reabrindo a pergunta de uma vez. Concordo com o @hkotsubo que a pergunta não é duplicada.

Comment: Realmente @hkotsubo, devo ter me enganado quando entendi a dúvida sendo relacionada à questão do escopo, e não do destructuring em si. Obrigado pela correção!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema não é ter mudado de `function` para *arrow function*. O problema é a forma que cada uma está recebendo os argumentos.

Na primeira você fez:

```js
function({ name })
```

Repare nos colchetes em volta de `name`. Esta é a sintaxe de [*destructuring assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (mais especificamente, veja a seção "*Unpacking fields from objects passed as a function parameter*").

Neste caso, significa que se eu passar um objeto como argumento da função, a variável `name` receberá o valor do atributo de mesmo nome daquele objeto. Por isso que ele pega somente o `name` de cada objeto.

Na *arrow function* você não colocou os colchetes, ou seja, o parâmetro `name` acabará recebendo todo o objeto, por isso ele acaba imprimindo todos os seus atributos.

Para resolver, basta usar o *destructuring assignment* na *arrow function* (ou seja, `({ name })` em vez de `(name)`):

```js
const names = heroes.map( ({ name }) => {
   return name;
 });
```

Ou então, faça do jeito mais "tradicional", sem o *destructuring assignment*, recebendo todo o objeto  e retornando o atributo desejado:

```js
// com arrow function
const names = heroes.map( (obj) => {
   return obj.name;
 });

// ou com function
const names = heroes.map(
  function(obj) {
    return obj.name;
  }
);
```

---

Lembrando que há diferenças entre `function` e *arrow function* (que neste caso específico não se aplica, mas é importante saber para não usá-las quando não for adequado), saiba mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/472205/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209506/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438933/112052).

Comment: Obrigada! Me ajudou muito