# Qual a diferença entre {} e ({}) em uma arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Nesta *arrow function*, para que retornasse um objeto por que foi necessário o parenteses?

```
const calculator = (number1, number2) => ({
  sum: number1 + number2,
  mult: number1 * number2,
  div: Math.floor(number1 / number2),
  sub: number1 - number2,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Achei um post aqui no Stackoverflow mesmo que acho que pode te ajudar nessa duvida, mas basicamente pelo que eu compreendi:

os () servem para e quando vc vai fazer uma ação aonde o código que a variável invoca  tiver mais de uma linha e quando e uma ação única que só será executada quando a variável for chamada

as {} e pra criar um bloco de ações que pode ter retorno tipo o os exemplos que foram colocados no post que me baseei

```
const fn1 = () => {
  return 'Olá, mundo!'
};

const fn2 = (x, y) => {
  // `if` é um exemplo de declaração (statement):
  if (x > y) {
    return 'X é maior que Y.';
  }
};
```

já quando temos ({}) e quando vc quer retornar um objeto e quando vc tem múltiplas linhas de código separados por ( , )
Não leve oq eu disse como verdade absoluta da uma pesquisada a mais tmb , e da uma olhada no post que aborda esse assuntos de parênteses e chaves

[Qual a diferença entre chaves e parênteses em uma arrow function no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438933/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-chaves-e-par%c3%aanteses-em-uma-arrow-function-no-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Muito obrigada!!

Comment: Não há de que :)